# Form only saving when inputs lost focus

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource, formview

I'm using a form (`FormView`) with databinding (`ObjectDataSource`) and all my input fields are bound by using `'<%# Bind("field") %>'`.

Everything works fine, but I have two problems (which I found various hints about like using `this.Validate()` or `.EndEdit()` - but none seem to work):

- Entries are only saved after leaving the input field so it looses focus

Let's say I have a textbox with an ID of Name and enter "George". When I would tab to the next textbox or when I click somewhere else and click save - everything is saved. But when I keep the focus in the textbox the value is not saved. Why is this happening? What magic can I use to circumvent this (JavaScript to the rescue?).

- I set a textbox's field value (`element.value`) via Javascript (upon selecting something in a combobox).

The same problem as above applies, only when I give the textbox focus and tab out the value is saved. This creates the problem that I only want the user to choose something in the combobox (the textbox is updated accordingly) and move on - I don't want the user to click into the textbox afterwards and tab out again.

---

Edit:

The second problem I resolved now by setting the focus onto my textbox via Javascript (`textbox.focus();`) and right after set the focus back to the combobox (`combobox.focus();`) and that does the trick - this seems fairly hackish to me, doesn't it?

---

I'm assuming this is fairly common, but my mighty Google fu hasn't help me find a simple solution.

Comment: Did you try forcing the focus on the button being clicked and then submit?

Comment: No, but I could do that for the one field I'm filling with JS - the general save problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue can crop up in Winforms development when working with `DataGridView` controls. I typically attach some logic to the submit button's `Click` event to cause the `DataGridView` to validate. I suspect a similar solution would work for you here.

Comment: Been there, done that. My save button has a `this.Validate()` and I added some `Page.Validate()` on the UserControls which contain the fields to be saved.